# How we can write test case for below DB connection statement

Tags: junit

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.URL),yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.USERNAME), yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.PASSWORD));`

In Test class I write below statements but its throwing NullPointerException
`when(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.URL)).thenReturn("url"); when(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.USERNAME)).thenReturn("user"); when(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.PASSWORD)).thenReturn("pass");`

Can you please help us why I am getting error and How can cover it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

To write test cases for the DB connection statement, you can create a mock object for the yamlConfig and then use the when method to mock the values for URL, USERNAME, and PASSWORD.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DBConnectionTest {

    @Test
    public void testDBConnection() throws Exception {
        
        // Create mock object for yamlConfig
        YamlConfig yamlConfig = mock(YamlConfig.class);

        // Mock the values for URL, USERNAME, and PASSWORD
        when(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.URL)).thenReturn("url");
        when(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.USERNAME)).thenReturn("user");
        when(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.PASSWORD)).thenReturn("pass");

        // Create connection object
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.URL),
                                                       yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.USERNAME),
                                                       yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.PASSWORD));
        
        // Assert that connection is not null
        assertNotNull(conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting below error "WrongTypeOfReturnValue 
String cannot be..."